# Tikz circle node pie

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

I would like a tikz circle node to be a pie chart. I have following code:

```
\tikzstyle{bus} = [draw, circle, minimum size=2em,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{busg} = [draw, circle, minimum size=2em,inner sep=0pt,color=red]
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [busg] (1) {1};
\node [bus, above =8em of 1] (5) {5};
\node [busg, right=3em of 1] (2) {2};
\draw (1) -- (5);
\draw (1) -- (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

How can I fill node 1 with 60% and node 2 with 30%?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution uses a `path picture` option to fill part of the circle. It doesn't need `backgrounds` library.

The `pienode` style is defined with 2 arguments, the first defines circle minimum size and the second is the percentage (0 to 100) to be filled.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    bus/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=2em, inner sep=0pt},
    pienode/.style 2 args={
    circle, minimum size=#1, 
    draw=red, text=red,
    inner sep=0pt,
    path picture={\fill[red!30] (path picture bounding box.center) 
        -- ++(0:#1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=3.6*#2, radius=#1]
        --cycle;}}]

\node[pienode={2em}{60}] (1) {1};
\node[bus, above=8em of 1] (5) {5};
\node[pienode={2em}{25}, right=3em of 1] (2) {2};

\draw (1)--(5) (1)--(2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I make the white space inside the circle (where there's no red) be a different color?

Comment: Add option fill= color to the desired nodes

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like

```
\fill [red!40] (1.center) -- (1.0) arc[start angle=0,delta angle=360*0.6,radius=1em] -- cycle;
```

Here `1.0` is the same as `1.east`, the `0` indicates degrees. The radius of the `arc` is set to half the `minimum size` of the `node`.

The `backgrounds` library helps you with drawing the fill behind the node itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
 bus/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=2em,inner sep=0pt},
 busg/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=2em,inner sep=0pt,color=red}
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [busg] (1) {1};
\node [bus, above=8em of 1] (5) {5};
\node [busg, right=3em of 1] (2) {2};
\draw (1) -- (5);
\draw (1) -- (2);\fill [red!40] (1.center) -- (1.0) arc[start angle=0,delta angle=360*0.6,radius=1em] -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill [red!40] (1.center) -- (1.0) arc[start angle=0,delta angle=360*0.6,radius=1em] -- cycle;
\fill [red!40] (2.center) -- (2.0) arc[start angle=0,delta angle=360*0.3,radius=1em] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For convenience one can wrap it in a macro, and include a calculation of the node/arc radius:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
 bus/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=2em,inner sep=0pt},
 busg/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=2em,inner sep=0pt,color=red}
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,calc}
\newcommand\NodePie[4][red!40]{%
% optional argument #1: fill color
% #2: node name
% #3: start angle
% #4: fraction (e.g. 0.3 for 30%)
\fill let
\p1=(#2.center), \p2=(#2.east), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,0)}
in
[#1] (#2.center) -- (#2.#3) arc[start angle=#3,delta angle=360*#4,radius=\n1] -- cycle;
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [busg] (1) {1};
\node [bus, above=8em of 1] (5) {5};
\node [busg, right=3em of 1] (2) {2};
\draw (1) -- (5);
\draw (1) -- (2);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\NodePie{1}{0}{0.6}
\NodePie[blue!30]{2}{30}{0.3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```